Capistrano: Puma doesn't start the server (Ubuntu)
I have a Rails app that I am trying to deploy to the Ubuntu server. This server is on DigitalOcean and it is the 1-click Rails package.
The Rails app uses Capistrano - here are the gems that I installed:
gem 'puma', '~> 6.4', '>= 6.4.2'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'capistrano3-puma', '6.0.0.beta.1'

Capfile:
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'

require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/puma'

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Systemd

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }

config/deploy.rb:
lock "~> 3.18.1"

server 'MY_IP', user: 'rails', port: 22, roles: %i[web app db], primary: true
set :application,     'my_proj'
set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:company/my_proj.git'
set :branch,          'main'

set :bundle_cmd, "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/bundle" # which bundle (on the server)
set :bundle_dir, "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2"

set :rvm_custom_path, '/usr/share/rvm' # which rvm
set :rvm_bin_path,    '/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/bin/ruby' # which ruby

set :deploy_to,       "/home/rails/my_proj"
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache

set :assets_manifests, lambda {
  [release_path.join('public', fetch(:assets_prefix), '.manifest.json')]
}

append :linked_files, *%w[config/master.key]
set :linked_dirs, %w[log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/assets public/uploads]

set :keep_releases, 5

config/puma.rb:
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production"
  require "concurrent-ruby"
  worker_count = Integer(ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { Concurrent.physical_processor_count })
  workers worker_count if worker_count > 1
end

worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

plugin :tmp_restart

On the server - /etc/systemd/system/rails.service - this was the default pre-installed rails service on the Ubuntu server:
[Unit]
Description=MyProjApp
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rails
Group=rails
#WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/example/
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/my_proj/current
#ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma'
#ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/bundle exec puma -e production -C ./config/puma.rb config.ru
ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma -C /home/rails/my_proj/current/config/puma/production.rb
PIDFile=/home/rails/my_proj/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid

StandardOutput=append:/home/rails/my_proj/current/log/puma_access.log
StandardError=append:/home/rails/my_proj/current/log/puma_error.log
#SyslogIdentifier=redata-puma

TimeoutSec=30s
RestartSec=30s
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails:
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/rails/my_proj/shared/tmp/sockets/my_proj-puma.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server deferred;

    server_name _;
    root /home/rails/my_proj/current/public;
    access_log /home/rails/my_proj/current/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/rails/my_proj/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
    location @puma {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://puma;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}

systemctl status nginx:
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-04-13 19:05:02 UTC; 20h ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
   Main PID: 55403 (nginx)
      Tasks: 16 (limit: 1116)
     Memory: 50.8M
        CPU: 19.947s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─55403 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             ├─97015 "Passenger watchdog" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" >
             ├─97018 "Passenger core" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             └─97032 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

Apr 14 11:37:34 SERVER nginx[95575]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Apr 14 11:37:34 SERVER nginx[95575]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on [::]:80, ignored
Apr 14 11:37:34 SERVER systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Apr 14 11:52:58 SERVER systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 14 11:52:58 SERVER nginx[96319]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Apr 14 11:52:58 SERVER nginx[96319]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on [::]:80, ignored
Apr 14 11:52:58 SERVER systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Apr 14 12:09:46 SERVER systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 14 12:09:46 SERVER nginx[97011]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Apr 14 12:09:46 SERVER systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

When I run cap production deploy, the received the following error:
/bin/systemctl stdout: Nothing written
/bin/systemctl stderr: Failed to start my_proj_puma_production.service: Unit my_proj_puma_production.service not found.

It looks that Puma is looking for the service file under a different name. How do I find where to specify the location of my /etc/systemd/system/rails.service?
Right now if I put the server IP to the browser, there's the This site can’t be reached IP refused to connect. error. I think the nginx setup might be a bit off as well. I tried to piece the configuration together from multiple tutorials, yet not successful.

Update: So nginx is actually not running either. I run sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start on the server and get this output:
Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
 failed!

systemctl status nginx.service outputs
× nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-04-14 16:08:57 UTC; 20s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 122858 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 122859 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 54ms


The problem is that capistrano3-puma with the version 6.0.0.beta.1 as default, searches for a user service that is located under /home/someuser/.config/systemd/user/<application_name>puma_<stage_name>.service.
To use the system services under /etc/systemd/system, you have to do adjust this:

Rename the old Services from <puma_application>_name_<stage_name>.service to <application_name>_puma_<stage_name>.service
Add the set :systemctl_user, :system in to your deploy.rb if you want to use it for every stage or in the separated stage files.

Example deploy.rb:
lock "~> 3.19.1"

set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"

set :linked_dirs, ...
set :linked_files, ...

set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup

set :systemctl_user, :system

set :rbenv_ruby, '3.3.3'

For example in the deploy/staging.rb just add it the same way, as you would set other variables/constants.
